# Stored Procedures with parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

My question is : A Stored Procedure that receives a given flight and a given date as input, and displays a customer call list, which includes name, address and phone number as output.
The query is simple, I can get all the data from a single table but, I don’t know how to take an input while running the procedure and then comparing it with the values inside.
The query is:

```
select NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE
    FROM SCH_FLIGHTS SF, PASSENGERS P
    WHERE SF.DATE(input) = P.DATE
```

Would highly appreciate you helping me on the same....just need to convert that query into a stored procedure which takes 2 inputs, a date and a flight_no as mentioned in the question above.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx. Its a good tutorial.

Comment: What are the two inputs you want to pass in?  I C SF.DATE(input), what is the other?

Comment: Please clarify which flavour of RDBMS you are using.  SQL is (largely) standard across all flovours, but stored procedures are bespoke for each product.  Your tag says [mysql] but the error meassage you include your comment on Bernard's response is from Oracle Pl/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

To create the SP (don't know the exact datatypes so i am just guessing) :

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE NameOfProcedure(input VARCHAR(32))
 BEGIN
     select NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE
    FROM SCH_FLIGHTS SF, PASSENGERS P
    WHERE SF.DATE(input) = P.DATE
END
//
```

your PHP code would look somthing like this (TODO replace $input by query parameter for security reasons):
$result = $db->query("call NameOfProcedure($input)");

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
 following:
 := . ) , @ % default character


this is the error i am getting.

Comment: @user902243 This is confusing. Are you using MySql?  The error message looks like an Oracle message.